# How to check for duplicates before inserting into database?

Tags: php, sql, database, favorites

So I made a function to add photos to favorites, how do I make it so I don't keep adding the same images?

My code:

```
function addToFavorites($fileName)
{
    global $conn;
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $imageId = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "insert into favorites set UserEmail='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email)."', ImageID=".$imageId;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let the database do the work!  Simply define a unique constraint or index on the table:

```
alter table favorites add constraint unq_favorites_useremail_imageid
    unique (useremail, imageid);
```

With this constraint in place, the database will return an error if you attempt to insert a duplicate.

If you want to avoid the error, you can use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into favorites (UserEmail, ImageId)
    values (?, ?)
    on duplicate key update ImageId = values(ImageId);
```

Some notes about this:

- The `?` is a *parameter placeholder*.  Learn to use parameters rather than munging values in query strings.
- This does not use `set`.  That is a MySQL extension.  There is no advantage in this case; you might as well use the standard syntax.
- The `on duplicate key` is a no-operation, but it prevents the code from returning an error when there is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks this works, I just set the values into ```values=("","");``` so it wont show anything. Also is there a way to do this with code on my php script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid errors like Gordon Linof said you have execute query:

```html
SELECT FROM favorites WHERE UserEmail='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email)."' AND ImageID=".$imageId
```

and if it returns 0 records to execute the insert one. This is the safest way.